# CBFS c# - Read some bytes from file inside event handler

Tags: c#, minifilter

I'm writing my MD thesis and I've used CBFS Filter component (trial) as great helper library to test my work. Writing a Windows minifilter driver is a real pain. I'm just stumbled upon a couple of extra functionalities I want to try to implement but I cannot figure out how to do them (I filter a specific file extension). They are:

- Read some file content on AfterOpen event (I just need to read the first 1K from file to test some conditions and continue/refuse to go further)
- Alternatively can I force to allow only whole-file reading to be sure to have full file content in AfterRead event and eventually, replace buffer content with all 0s if conditions don't hold?

Comment: FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FILENAME);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);  If you want to read more than change the zero (offset) to new value.

Comment: This works but I don't know if it creates a series of "circular" event callbacks. I've tired it but in my logs I find a lot of "beforeRead" events firing and I don't know if it is the OS doing something else other than me. Thanks.